# Where is the documentation for build.gradle's `android` block?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In a build.gradle, we have the android block. From my limited understanding of Android Gradle Plugin (and Groovy/ Kotlin), this is a method/ (or function?) called `android` which accepts 1 argument, a closure.

```kotlin
android {
    compileSdkVersion(AppConfig.compileSdkVersion)
    buildToolsVersion(AppConfig.buildToolsVersion)
}
```

I was not able to find any documentation about `android`, both on the Google Developer website and Gradle.org. It doesn't help that the function has the same name as the whole operating system. Any documentation about Android Gradle plugin would be helpful, as it seems like information about it is pepperred all over Android docs. So far, I can search what each property means (e.g. `applicationId`, `testInstrumentationRunner`), but I want to see all the properties which `android` has, which is where the documentation comes in handy.

What sparked all these questions was this ["Introduction to Groovy and Gradle"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHhf1xG0pIA)

I was able to get the "package name" (maybe) for the `android` method with autocomplete in Android Studio: `com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModule`, but cannot find source code or documentation...

Answer (score 1):

It is described in android gradle plugin documentation under the class name AppExtension.  Here's a link [//google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/3.3/com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.html](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/3.3/com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.html)

Answer (score -4):

Please note that the `android` keyword mentioned in your question is not a function / method.

The `android { }` is an android block is where you configure all your Android-specific build options.

Also, as of now there is no specific document dedicated to this block.
However, just to assist you, I have identified following attributes which can be placed inside this block.

```html
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
    
    }

    buildTypes {
        
    }
    compileOptions {
        
    }
    kotlinOptions {
       
    }
    packagingOptions {
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Gradle files use a domain specific language (DSL) based on Groovy. All blocks in Gradle files are therefore method calls that take a closure (something like a lambda function). Check out the links in the answer of Martin Zeitler on how the DSL is implemented.